# HEVC/x265 :: VLC Player GPU Hardware Acceleration :: Intel HD Graphics 4400

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, gpu, hardware-acceleration, h.265

I'm using a Laptop with configurations Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310U Haswell CPU / Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 GPU / Windows 7. 
I've installed latest drivers (10.18.14.4414) to support HEVC/x265 Hardware Accleration.

DXVA Checker shows it supports *HEVC_VLD_Main / DXVA2 / SD HD FHD 4K*.

When Play x264 videos VLC Playter debug log shows that it is using the GPU for decoding.

```
avcodec info: Using DXVA2 (Intel(R) HD Graphics Family, vendor 32902(Intel), device 2582, revision 11) for hardware decoding.
```

But while playing x265 it is not using the GPU to decode the HEVC  video and the CPU utilization is comparatively higher.
Please help to propertly configure vlc to utlize the GPU to decode HEVC video.

I'm trying to play the sample video downloaded from http://jell.yfish.us/ of HEVC Main Profile Level 4 and other video of 3.1 Level.

```
ID                             : 1
Format                         : HEVC
Format/Info                    : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                 : Main@L4@Main
Codec ID                       : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                       : 30s 97ms
Bit rate                       : 2 772 Kbps
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 29.970 fps
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.045
Stream size                    : 9.94 MiB (98%)
Writing library                : x265 1.8+190-75d1c62d8f0c:[Windows][MSVC 1700][64 bit] 8bit
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating drivers doesn't make your device more capable, however you may wish it to. HD Graphics 4400 (which comes with your CPU) doesn't support HEVC coding. The drivers are generally common, so the changelogs can be misleading. In other words, the driver contains code to decode HEVC using GPU, but the hardware has no idea on how to use it.

Points to consider:

No intel iGPU supports 10-bit HEVC

Braswell or Skylake support 8-bit HEVC, but you're using Haswell

EDIT: It looks like your GPU does support 8-bit HEVC through the latest driver (though this seems odd to me). In that case you're probably playing 10-bit video. I'll try to get more info on this.

Comment: Thank you Radial for quick response.
I'm confused wiht this post https://communities.intel.com/thread/59216 it says HEVC 8 bit is available.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is very interesting, as drivers cannot generally add decode functionality. Are you sure the video you're playing is 8-bit?

Comment: Hi  Radial Apps, Please find above the updated question with video codec information. The video is HEVC Main Profile Level 4 8-Bit and other video of 3.1 Level.

Answer (score 0):

VLC player doesn't [support](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding) GPU decoding for H.265 videos. Try Media Player classic which can use GPU using decoders such as LAV